# Как остановить обратный отсчет?

Tags: javascript

Есть счетчик обратного отсчета

```
   function countDown() {
      let standart = moment().tz("Europe/Moscow").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
      let nowDay = moment(standart, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
      var eventDay = moment('2023-05-20 18:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
      let timers = moment(nowDay, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').countdown(eventDay, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").toString();
      let countDw = guild.channels.cache.get("1105888140683448792");
      countDw.setName("Осталось: " + timers);
   }
   setInterval(countDown, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

Когда счетчик доходит до конца, он начинает отсчет вперед. Т.е.  в 18:01 он пишет, что осталась 1 минута, в 18:02 - осталось 2 минуты и т.д.

Как остановить отсчет?

Comment: простой пример отмены setInterval - [clearInterval()](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval), у вас то же самое, только условием будет "конец" счетчика

Comment: достаточно сравнить nowDay > eventDay и если это правда, то можно и остановить счетчик, и ничего не выводить

Comment: Не очень понимаю как сравнить время

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```js
function countDown() {
   let standart = moment().tz("Europe/Moscow").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
   let nowDay = moment(standart, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
   var eventDay = moment('2023-05-20 18:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
   let timers = moment(nowDay, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').countdown(eventDay, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").toString();
   let countDw = guild.channels.cache.get("1105888140683448792");
   countDw.setName("Осталось: " + timers);
}

let interval = setInterval(countDown, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

Потом, когда вам нужно остановить отсчёт:

```js
clearInterval(interval);
```

Вышеуказанное действие можно обернуть в функцию и выполнять где надо.

Comment: Как вы собираетесь определять, когда остановить отсчёт?

Comment: @ΝNL993 я никуда не собираюсь.))) автор вопроса сам решит, когда останавливать

Comment: или вам надо полный код, чтобы он всё в функции `countDown` делать?

Comment: Очень смешно. Автор вопроса уже решил, когда время дойдёт до 2023-05-20 18:00.

Comment: `или вам надо полный код` -- вы просто взяли ответ с комментария, не добавив ничего своего, конечно же надо.

Comment: ахахахаха мне тоже смешно

Comment: Пожалуйста, выносите "Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте. Я всегда могу дополнить ответ." в комментарий. Это не является ответом и никакой ценности не несёт.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar окей